# Oracle SQL where clauses

Tags: oracle, where-clause

I would like to select all customers (id_cust attribute) and sum of income (income attrib.) in customertable which have transaction (income) in year 2016 (incomedate attrib) but they don't have transaction (income) in 2017. So all transaction are in one table.

```
id_cust  income   incomedate
123      101       2/5/2016
123      211       6/1/2017
221      900       9/7/2017
221      300       8/9/2016
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum of income per customer

```
select sum(income),id_cust
from customertable
group by id_cust
```

Sum of income per customer per year

```
select sum(income),id_cust,to_char(incomedate,'YYYY') year
from customertable
group by id_cust,to_char(incomedate,'YYYY')
```

Comment: I'm already used select as you suggest, but with long list of customer (>9000) and transaction >21000 is not useful. I would like to view only customer which as not active in 2017, but in 2016 they was. So in where clauses I need to add condition income = 0 in YY=17 , but in YY=16 are income >0.... how to write?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
select t1.id_cust, sum(t1.income)
from customertable t1
WHERE 
to_char(t1.incomedate, 'YYYY') = '2016'
and not exists (
      SELECT 1
      FROM customertable t2
      WHERE t2.id_cust = t1.id_cust
      AND to_char(t2.incomedate,'YYYY') = '2017'
)
group by t1.id_cust;
```

Hope it help.

Comment: It's works, Thx, I didn't know for .....  and not exists ...  condition!